# Does OneDrive Business have a superuser concept?

Tags: 2013, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, onedrive

The problem to solve: use the SharePoint 2013 REST API to browse all OneDrive users and all directories and files within the context of a OneDrive Business account. I need to fetch directory, file and user metadata, and desire a way to do that from a single superuser account.

Does the default content access account provide that capability? If not, does SharePoint 2013 even allow this?

Answer (score 3):

If this is SharePoint Online, you must grant a secondary account with Site Collection Owner access to each ODfB site. If this is SharePoint on-prem, it is easier as you can grant an account Full Read (or Full Control) on the Web Application User Policy instead.